# How to populate picker options from async SQLite datasource in MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, picker

I need to have a picker (or some other control) offering the user options inside a MVVM implementation (based on [Xamarin.Forms MVVM: How to Work with SQLite DB(C# — Xaml)](https://medium.com/swlh/xamarin-forms-mvvm-how-to-work-with-sqlite-db-c-xaml-26fcae303edd)) but cant see how to load the async options into the binding.

I have a detail edit screen for a record type called viewings, with straight forward entry fields bound to a ViewingDetailViewingModel.
`...BindingContext = new ViewingDetailViewModel(viewModel ?? new ViewingViewModel(), viewingStore, pageService, viewingsRestStore);` in the XAML's codebehind.

In addition to the relatively straight forward entry cells binding to properties of the Viewing's model (forgive me if I don't use the correct nomenclature, new to this), I want to have one of the fields use a picker to save a Client's id based on the user selecting a client.

So I'm guessing, as the SQLite clientstore's get return is async, I should have a command that is triggered from somewhere, I imagine ideally from the codebehind's onAppearing method that updates an IList of Clients that the picker binds to - though I encounter two problems here:

1. I can't figure out how to trigger the command from there so I'm trying to execute it from the end of the viewmodel's constructor for now.
2. Doing that (although I don't think because of that), the app crashes once it tries to add the first client to the list while looping through the get results with "...System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
   at AgentApp.ViewingDetailViewModel.LoadClients (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] Clients)..."

so in my XAML I have

```
<EntryCell Label="Agt_description" Text="{Binding Path=Viewing.Agt_description}" />
                <ViewCell >
                    <Picker Title="Select a client" ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}"  ItemDisplayBinding ="{Binding Agt_FirstName}" />
                </ViewCell>
```

In the view's code-behind:

```
 public ViewingDetailPage(ViewingViewModel viewModel)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ViewingDetailPage()");
            InitializeComponent();
            var viewingStore = new SQLiteViewingStore(DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>());
            var viewingsRestStore = new RESTViewingStore();
            var pageService = new PageService();
            bool isNewViewing = (viewModel.Agt_name == " ");
            Title = (isNewViewing) ? "New Viewing" : "Edit Viewing";
            if (isNewViewing)
            {
                var app = Application.Current as App;
                viewModel.Agt_ac = app.AgencyIdInt;
                viewModel.Agt_b = app.BranchIDInt;
                viewModel.Agt_at = app.AccountIdInt;
            }
            BindingContext = new ViewingDetailViewModel(viewModel ?? new ViewingViewModel(), viewingStore, pageService, viewingsRestStore);
        }
```

and then the ViewingDetailViewModel:

```
class ViewingDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly IViewingStore _viewingStore;
        private readonly IViewingStore _viewingRestStore;
        private readonly IPageService _pageService;
        public Viewing Viewing { get; private set; }
        public ICommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }

        //trying
        public ICommand LoadClientsCommand { get; private set; }
        private IClientStore _clientStore;
        private IList<ClientViewModel> _clients;
        public IList<ClientViewModel> Clients
        {
            get { return _clients; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _clients, value); }   // from BaseViewModel, implements OnPropertyChanged()
        }
        //

        public ViewingDetailViewModel(ViewingViewModel viewModel, IViewingStore viewingStore, IPageService pageService, IViewingStore viewingRestStore)
        {
                        var app = Application.Current as App;
            if (viewModel == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(viewModel));

            _pageService = pageService;
            _viewingStore = viewingStore;
            _viewingRestStore = viewingRestStore;

            LoadClientsCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadClients());

            SaveCommand = new Command(async () =>
            {
                                var SaveDBTask = SaveDB("primary");
                var SaveRESTTask = SaveRest();
                                var saveTasks = new List<Task> { SaveDBTask, SaveRESTTask };
                while (saveTasks.Count > 0)
                {
                    Task finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(saveTasks);
                    if (finishedTask == SaveDBTask)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("SaveDBTask finished:" + SaveDBTask);
                    }
                    else if (finishedTask == SaveRESTTask)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("SaveRESTTask finished, do db update:" + SaveRESTTask);
                        await SaveDB("secondary update");
                    }
                    saveTasks.Remove(finishedTask);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Save tasks complete.");
            });

            Viewing = new Viewing
            {
                Id = viewModel.Id,
                Agt_description = viewModel.Agt_description,
                Agt_name = viewModel.Agt_name,
                RemoteId = viewModel.RemoteId,
                Agt_ac = viewModel.Agt_ac > 0 ? viewModel.Agt_ac : app.AgencyIdInt,
                Agt_b = viewModel.Agt_b > 0 ? viewModel.Agt_b : app.BranchIDInt,
                Agt_at = viewModel.Agt_at > 0 ? viewModel.Agt_at : app.AccountIdInt,
                Agt_pr = viewModel.Agt_pr,
                Agt_datetime_scheduled = viewModel.Agt_datetime_scheduled,
                Agt_datetime_start = viewModel.Agt_datetime_start,
                Agt_datetime_end = viewModel.Agt_datetime_end,
                StatusLocal = viewModel.StatusLocal,
                CreatedLocal = viewModel.CreatedLocal,
                ModifiedLocal = viewModel.ModifiedLocal,
                CreatedRemote = viewModel.CreatedRemote,
                ModifiedRemote = viewModel.ModifiedRemote,
                LastSync = viewModel.LastSync,
            };

            LoadClientsCommand.Execute(null);//doubt this is a good idea
        }

        async Task LoadClients()
        {
            _clientStore = new SQLiteClientStore(DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>());
            var clients = await _clientStore.GetClientsAsync();
            foreach (var client in clients)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("for client:" + client.Agt_FirstName);
                Clients.Add(new ClientViewModel(client)); //crashes around here
            }
        }

        async Task SaveDB(string savetype)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Viewing.Agt_name))
            {
                await _pageService.DisplayAlert("Error", "Please enter the name.", "OK");
                return;
            }
            if (Viewing.Id == 0)
            {
                await _viewingStore.AddViewing(Viewing);
                MessagingCenter.Send(this, Events.ViewingAdded, Viewing);
            }
            else
            {
                await _viewingStore.UpdateViewing(Viewing);
                MessagingCenter.Send(this, Events.ViewingUpdated, Viewing);
            }
            if (savetype == "primary")
                await _pageService.PopAsync();
        }

        async Task SaveRest()
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Viewing.Agt_name))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("REST save could not, invalid name.");
                return;
            }
            if (Viewing.RemoteId == 0)
            {
                await _viewingRestStore.AddViewing(Viewing);
            }
            else
            {
                await _viewingRestStore.UpdateViewing(Viewing);
                MessagingCenter.Send(this, Events.ViewingUpdated, Viewing);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm a complete newb coming from a simple php background and all this OOP complexity is confusing me somewhat; I'm probably making a whole lot of really stupid mistakes - and maybe I'm overcomplicating things - I hope someone can point me at a good simple way of loading the picker's async data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You thread is large, I an not sure what is your problem, you want to get data from sqlite db and display in picker? It is very large data, so you using async?

Comment: It probably won't be very large but it might become so, or it might get data from a REST resource, and I understand I shouldn't stall the main/UI thread waiting to get the results. I think the main part of my question is, if I have a command that will load the data where and how should I trigger that command, e.g. how do I reference the command in the ViewModewl from the View's code-behind's onAppearing()?

Comment: Secondarily, I don't understand the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" business which seems to happen at 
` Clients.Add(new ClientViewModel(client)); ` in async Task LoadClients()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it doesn't look like you are instantiating the `Clients` property anywhere. That is why you would get a `NullReferenceException`

Second, if you are adding items to a `IList` no one will get notified that something was added to this collection. Instead, you should consider changing the type to `ObservableCollection` instead, that helps you doing so.

So changing the code for `Clients` to:

```
public ObservableCollection<ClientViewModel> Clients { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<ClientViewModel>();
```

This will probably solve most of your issues with UI not updating and `Clients` being null when you try populating it.